# Flexbox conundrum - how to nest flex box in layers of custom elements and get the desired result with media queries

Tags: css, flexbox

This is a question about alignment with flexbox when used in a column direction.  The trouble I'm finding is that all the documentation uses examples in rows, and certain things don't seem to translate when changing the axis.

I'm building a web single page web app which is structured in multiple lays of custom elements. I exclude selection between pages for simplicity sake, so this view is a summary of the contents of one page, the others being essentially swapped out (using `litHtml` and the `cache` directive controlled by a dynamic object selection).  My hierarchy is like this (apart from the `<app-page>` element, all the other elements have their content solely in the shadowroot, so not as children as shown here.  `<app-page>` is more of a utility item and so it has slots defined in the shadow root and its real children are hoisted in to them.  I use some lines to indicate the difference between its shadow root and its real children. `<app-error>` will have no content most of the time - it gains content when there is an error, and at that point `<app-session>` displays no content.

```
<main-app>
  <header>My App Header Bar with menu button and App-logo etc</header>
  <section>
    <app-error></app-error>
    <app-session>
      <app-verify-email>
        <app-page>
          <--
            <header>Different sort of Logo </header>
            <slot></slot>
            <div id="wedge"></div>
            <slot name="action></slot>
          -->
          <h1>Verify Email Header</h1>
          <p>Some text about Verifying Email</p>
          <input type="email" value="${this.email}"/.
          <button slot="action">Send</button>
          <button slot="action>Cancel</button>
        </app-page>
      </app-verify-email>`,
    </app-session>
  </section>
</main-app>`
```

My objective is as follows the normal case I assume we have a mobile phone, where the main-app's header bar will be at the bottom of the screen, to make the menu button on it close the the users thumb.  I achieve this by giving main-app a style of

```
:host {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  :host {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

To support the other elements in the chain, so they are all fully stretched, I have decided to try them with

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

this allows them to fill out to full content, but (I hope) allows `<app-session>` to collapse down when `<app-error>` has something to display (and it doesn't because the error stage will be selected.

The other consideration is, I want the rest of the content to nestle at the top EXCEPT the buttons inside the "action" slot.  Firstly in the normal case the buttons should be at the bottom just above the header bar, but in the wider screen situation they should be at the top immediately under the content.  I am trying to achieve by host styles as so:-

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#wedge {
  display: block;
  flex:1;
}
@media-query (min-width: 500px) {
  #wedge {
     display: none;
     flex:0;
  }
}
```

but its not working and I don't know why?

I've tried other options, like not using the wedge and instead putting `align-item: flex end;` on the button slot but that doesn't work either.

As I said above I am struggling to find flex box examples that are based on column layouts, so I could do with help working how how to achieve my objectives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a test case and have been working away at it to try and solve this.  The trick, I think is to be sparing with when something is a flex-box, but also to make use of height=100% to force not flexbox items to fill the space, so that its internal flexbox items can do their thing over the entire space.

The real clincher was the use of margin:auto as a way of pushing the button block to the bottom, even though the contents is justified to flex-start.  This appears to be the "standard" way of pushing items in a flex container apart;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      html {
        background: #ffffff;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
        min-height: 100vh;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        color: #333;
      }
      .main-app {
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        justify-content:flex-start;
      }
      .main-app>header {

          height: 64px;
          color:  white;
          background-color: #adcabd;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: space-between;
          align-items:center;
      }
      .main-app>section {
        height: calc(100vh - 64px);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .app-session {
        display:block;
        flex:1;
      }
      .app-verify-email {
        height: 100%;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .app-page{
        height:100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        max-width: 600px;
        justify-content: start;
        padding:10px;
      }
      .app-page header {
        height: 64px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
      }


      .action {
        display: flex;
        width:100%;
        flex-direction:row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        margin-top:auto;
      }

      @media (min-width: 500px) {
        .main-app {
          flex-direction: column;
        }
        .action {
          margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .app-page {
          min-width:600px;
          height: auto;
        }
      }
      @media (min-width: 501px) {
        .app-page {

          border-radius: 10px;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 38px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        }
      }



    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-app">
      <header><img src="/appimages/site_logo.png"/><div>v1.0.0</div></header>
      <section>
        <div class="app-error"><!--Error in progress--></div>
        <div class="app-session">
          <div class="app-verify-email">
            <div class="app-page">
              <header>Different sort of Logo </header>
              <section class="container">
                <h1>Verify Email Header</h1>
                <p>Some text about Verifying Email</p>
                <input type="email" value="alan@chandlerfamily.org.uk"/>
              </section>

              <div class="action">
                <button>Send</button>
                <button cancel>Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </app-page>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```